# ASP.NET MVC 3 with jQuery ajax to Load a PartialView

Tags: .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I got problem to request a PartialView using ajax
In my point of view everything looks find, but error show up like:

Request URL:http://localhost:4530/Home/ViewWorld
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found

Here are the codes:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "Home/ViewWorld", //'@Url.Action("viewWorld", "Home")',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (e) {
            alert(e);
    },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error[0]);
    }
    });
```

My controller look like this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Index/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ViewWorld()
    {
        return PartialView("_ContactMe");
    }

}
```

Global.asax:

```
routes.MapRoute( "Default", // Route name 
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters 
                new { controller = "Home", 
                      action = "ViewWorld", 
                      id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults 
                );
```

Can anyone help me to figure out why it does not works, thanks

Comment: What happends if you open the URL (http://localhost:4530/Home/ViewWorld) in your browser? Can you access any other Action?

Comment: do you have a route set up for that action ?

Comment: The error show up:

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /Home/ViewWorld

Comment: I have set up in the Global:
`routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "ViewWorld", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just missing a forward slash: "/Home/ViewWorld"

Comment: Tow things to try. 1) Include a data: {} parameter. 2) Any reason you can't do a POST?

Comment: Hi man, thx, problem fixed, the error is my route name is still using "Default", suppose to change it to other. Cheers

Comment: I just noticed your original url has a lower case "v" - it should be '@(Url.Action("ViewWorld","Home"))' - I think this is a safer syntax than the /Home/ViewWorld. HTH